# php 5.3 ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, ereg-replace

```
$this->Settings = array( "host" => $host , "user" => $user , "pass" => $pass );
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->Settings["name"] = ereg_replace  ("_", "", $this->db);
    $this->init();
```

I have an application that can't work after migrating to php 5.3 from php 5.2.

Even after i changed the ereg_replace line above to

`$this->aSettings["name"] = preg_replace("/_/", "", $this->db);`

It still doesn't get the settings from the db.

Comment: If the problem is that the value is not retrieved from the database then the problem is in your `$db` variable. Try to inspect its value: `var_dump($db)`

Answer (score 3):

There's no particular reason why your `preg_replace()` wouldn't work, but you could simply use `str_replace()` instead.

```
$this->Settings['Name'] = str_replace('_', '', $this->db);
```

This statement interests me though:

```
$this->db = $db;
```

Where is `$db` set? Follow that trail until you find where the real issue is,

Comment: thanks. yeah.. that's not the issue. it is hard to trace as there are no errors even when error reporting is set to all.

Comment: @PotentialCoder You need to share more of your code then, otherwise it's impossible to help you.